Does SpaceX post their planned trajectories publicly?
I live in a location where SpaceX launches are sometimes visible.  I know SpaceX posts planned launch times, but does it provide any information about the flight trajectory to the public?  I would like to use it to decide when it is worth trying to see a launch.

there may be some help in the asnwers to: How to determine rocket launch path for photography? and perhaps How can I find sources for Launch Trajectories? but it's more of finding several sources (basically flings with government agencies) and putting the information together than a single SpaceX "posting".
